# How is it called when one ellipse is "more elliptical" than another one?

Tags: geometry, definition

Assume you have two ellipses, $A$ and $B$. Now $A$ looks "flatter" than $B$ because its ratio $\frac{\text{major axis}}{\text{minor axis}}$ is bigger. This means it "looks less" than a circle. How is that called? More elliptical?

(I am looking for a description for my bachelor's thesis.)

[image: Ellipse]

Source: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Elps-slr.svg

Comment: In particular, the adjective should be "more eccentric".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Eccentricity is what you're looking for: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eccentricity_(mathematics)

Answer (score 1):

[Eccentricity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eccentricity_(mathematics)) would be best used to compare the relative "*obesity*" of ellipses.

Although, [Ellipticity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flattening) (aka Flattening) may also be a good measure of the elliptical nature of ellipses.

Comment: Just the other way, eccentrity is _inverse obesity_ — the more eccentric the ellipse, the thinner it is...